# What is best way to combine multiple fields in template preprocess?

Tags: 7, entities, theming

I have 3 fields I want to join into one line to wrap inside some tags.  Is template.php in a preprocess function the best place to do this?  I won't need the fields after I join them, so I assume I call hide() on them as well?

Comment: where exactly are you trying to display it? with in the node display or with in some views?

Comment: A node display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this using [hook_node_view()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7) or [theme_preprocess_node()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/template_preprocess_node/7), but I'm not sure which is the best way.

```
function MYMODULE_node_view($node, $view_mode = 'full', $langcode = NULL) {
    if($view_mode == 'full'){
        if($node->type == 'your_content_type'){     
            $field_1 = $node->content['your_field_1'];
            $field_2 = $node->content['your_field_2'];
            $field_3 = $node->content['your_field_3'];

            // remove individual fields
            unset($node->content['your_field_1']);
            unset($node->content['your_field_2']);
            unset($node->content['your_field_3']);

            // combine those fields in a tag
            $html = '<div id="some-id">';
            $html .= '<span>'.$field_1.'</span>';
            $html .= '<span>'.$field_2.'</span>';
            $html .= '<span>'.$field_3.'</span>';
            $html .= '</div>';

            $node->content['combined_field'] array(
                '#markup' => $html,
                '#weight' => 1
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Another way is to alter these from `THEME_preprocess_node()` in the template.php.

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['view_mode'] == 'full' && node_is_page($variables['node'])) {      
    $field1 = strip_tags($variables['content']['field_1']['#markup']);
    $field2 = strip_tags($variables['content']['field_2']['#markup']);

    // remove individual fields
    unset($variables['content']['field_1']);
    unset($variables['content']['field_2']);

    // combine those fields in a tag
    $variables['content']['combined_fields'] = array(
        '#markup' => '<div id="some_id">'.$field1.$field2.'</div>',
        '#weight' => 2
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This looks like what I want to do, but I really want to try it in template.php to minimize the code I've been touching.

Comment: @vintorg, check my updated answer.

Comment: Sithu, thanks.  That seems like the most logical place to do this.